# Can you sign app bundle from different PC / keystore

Tags: android, flutter, app-bundle

I uploaded my first app bundle from a desktop pc.

But now I want to upload an app bundle from a different pc (MacBook to be precise).

So I added additional sha-1 and sha-256 fingerprint in my console account and created a new upload-keystore.jks file.

But when I upload the new app-release.aab to play console it says:

> Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your App Bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:
> SHA1: xxx
> but the certificate used to sign the App Bundle you uploaded has a fingerprint:
> SHA1: yyy

So what do I do in this case?

PS: I tried cleaning my builds and cache and doing a new app build.

Comment: How about using the same key on both computers?

Comment: first thing is to check is are uploading your `app-release` file on the correct app sometimes you may by mistake go to the wrong application and try to update it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the old keystore.jks file, then it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Actually i just realized there was a big fat button on upload page saying "Change signing key"...

It allows you to set your new signing key to current keystore.jks

It worked for me.